# SWI-Prolog: replace value from map

Tags: dictionary, prolog

I have a map/3 with all values set, how can i change a value from the map, i want to change for example `map(2,3,"O")` to `map(2,3,"X")`, how can i change "O" from that position to "X" ?

Comment: please explain with a little example what you are expecting

Comment: so i initialized the map with some values and i want to change the stored values, but i get the error that i can't modify map because it's static so i did something else, but is there any way to modify static values like map that are built in prolog?

Answer (score 1):

```
:- dynamic map/3.

change_map(X,Y,Old,New) :- retract(map(X,Y,Old)), asserta(map(X,Y,New)).
```